# numpy array for sequential network: varying sequence length

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tf.keras

I have a **recurrent network (RNN)** whose task is to learn to **classify vectors** (float32) in two classes. My model is really simple so far:

```
model = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(units=10, input_shape=(None, len_vector)),
    Dense(1, activation="relu")
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30)
```

To train this network, I create a dataset with 1000 instances of sequences of vectors. When I create sequences with the same length each, the training works perfectly and the dataset has shape:

```
[<number of sequences>, <number of vectors in each sequence>, <number of floats in each vector>]
```

The problem is that my model must be able to work on sequence with various length. I don't know how (or even if it is possible) to create a numpy array where one dimension is not constant.

While searching a solution, I saw that setting the array `dtype=object` made it possible to assign list of different shapes to element of a numpy array, but the keras model will only accept `dtype="float32"`.

Is there a way I can make this numpy array dataset? Or should I change the algorithm to train the model? Or is the only solution to pad sequences with nul vectors to unify their length?

(Thanks for the help. I'm fairly new to deep learning so I apologize if I'm asking for something obvious.)

Answer (score 1):

Use Ragged Tensors, they provide you to make variable length inputs,

```
import numpy as np
_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 100))
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20,)(_input)
func = tf.keras.backend.function(inputs=_input, outputs=lstm)
rt = tf.ragged.constant([np.random.randn(1,34,100),
                         np.random.randn(1,55,100) ,
                         np.random.randn(1,60,100) ,
                         np.random.randn(1,70,100)])

func(rt[1])
```